# How do you know if something was manipulated in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form using jQuery that I need to manipulate the incoming data. The engine provides me a `text` field with decimal data, but it expects the POST data to be hexadecimal. So I convert it with jQuery to avoid the user from needing to re-enter it. Yes, I know it's pretty dumb, but it's out of my hands on the other end.

I tried to use `addClass()` to add a class (`hexified`) and then modified my selectors to not re-process. But when I reloaded the page with F5, Firefox kept the modified values, but cleared the class on me.

I tried making a hidden input that the server would ignore (so it always came back zero), but that seems to randomly not work.

I was thinking cookies, but that wouldn't help if you had the page open in multiple tabs, or how would I clear, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox the problem is likely due to caching. FF caches form field values very aggressively.

If you can live with the other implications, just add `autocomplete="off"` to the `<input/>`.

Comment: I will try and play with that tomorrow, thanks. Who knew that was the problem...!

Answer (score 1):

You could just start processing and stop if the first one starts with `0x`.

```
var $decToHexFields = $(".something");
if (!/^0x/i.test($decToHexFields.first().val()))
{
    // process fields
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, forgot to mention it. I didn't want to assume the user would put the 0x or # or something at the front.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are your best idea. Regardless if they're in multiple tabs, they'll share the same domain so they'll work. Have JQuery look for the cookie and add the class to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('form').attr('autocomplete','off');
});
```

This should disable firefox remembering the previous input value, but you lose the autocomplete-as-you-type feature